# Trekking maps of Svanetia available abroad?

Tags: maps, mountains, caucasus, georgia

Are there any trekking maps of Svanetia available abroad? I'd like to purchase the maps **before** arriving to Georgia.

The preferred map scale is at least 1:50.000, however 1:100.000 would also fit in last resort. It would be at best, if the actual tourist trails (if any) were shown there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

### Georgia trekking maps

[Georgia trekking maps](http://www.geoland.ge/en/products/maps/turistuli-salasqro-rukebi) covering part of Georgia are available from various international resellers, such as [omnimap](http://www.omnimap.com/catalog/int/georgia.htm) and [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/990117886X).  They cover part of the mountains of Georgia, and seem to include the province of Svanetia:

[image: Georgia trekking maps]

### Genshtab maps

As a former Soviet Union member state, Georgia is well-covered by the Genshtab maps, Soviet military topographic maps.  In a scale of 1:50.000, they cover the entire nation.  [Genshtab maps can be downloaded online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/21534/4904), or are for sale from various sources, such as the aforementioned omnimap, or from [geostatial.com (quite expensive)](http://www.geospatial.com/store/type/country/term/geo/text/georgia/).

Comment: Hi gerrit! The first link you have here is dead, at least as of today, March 15, 2018. I just wanted to let you know!